# AWS API. CloudFront Distribution disable

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront

How do disable AWS CloudFront Distribution via api - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/CloudFront.html. I can't find proper function.

Final goal is delete distribution (deleteDistribution), but it requires disabling firstly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to delete a distribution, you should first use [`updateDistribution`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/CloudFront.html#updateDistribution-property) to disable the distribution (setting enabled to `false`), and then call [`deleteDistribution`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/CloudFront.html#deleteDistribution-property) to delete it.

Answer (score 0):

Call `updateDistribution(params, callback)` with `params.DistributionConfig.Enabled = false`.

The [SDK documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/CloudFront.html) states:

> Enabled — required — (Boolean)
>
> From this field, you can enable or disable the selected distribution.